# Use linq to iterate through large DB tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have two tables: `Foo` and `Bar`. For each row in `Foo`, I now want to add a row in `Bar` which references the respective `Foo` record. `Foo` will likely contain several millions of records.

Normally this answer would have been perfect: [linq to sql - loop through table data and set value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238144/linq-to-sql-loop-through-table-data-and-set-value). But as it says on the tin, using the following line is not particularly ideal for large tables.

```
List<User> users = dc.Users.ToList();
```

Since caching the entire table in a `List<>` is not going to work, what other options do I have? Is there an elegant way to "page through" the records, for instance? Since I am quite sure that this is a relatively common problem, I think it's likely that there is a best practice for this too. I have not been able to find it, however.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do with this data in tables?

Comment: Is there any reason at all why you need to do this in code? Batch processing like this is generally much easier and faster in the database, using a simple SQL query or stored procedure.

Comment: Why can't you use a `foreach` instead of using `ToList()`? And if you need to read million of rows, it is normally better (if possible) to disable `ObjectTrackingEnabled`

Answer (score 3):

Your talking about several million rows of data, then Linq is not your friend.

Consider using a stored procedure or, if you like, `DbContext.ExecuteCommand`.

Both will result in a huge performance gain.

Comment: This is the answer... you want that operation to happen within the DB.

Answer (score 1):

You can work with predefined batches using `.Skip()` and `.Take()` methods. Another thing to consider is using a trigger so that you don't need to worry about the second table at all.